# Implementing ClipTo function on fabricjs canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, svg, fabricjs

I am able to clip my canvas to a shape if I hardcode the SVG when the canvas initially loads. Now I am trying to do this with a click function. The challenge is that since everything has loaded, when I click on it and load the clipping function, it clears my canvas and leaves just the shape and background. I'm looking for ideas on how to implement this. I only know how to load the `opts` in a `new` `fabric.canvas` function. I suspect I will have to get the current canvas data and then apply the `opts` parameter to it, but I am not sure the best way to do it. Here is my code:

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('imageCanvas');

$('#shape').on('click', function(){

var clipPath = new fabric.Path("M161.469,0.007 C161.469,0.007 214.694,96.481 214.694,96.481 C214.694,96.481 322.948,117.266 322.948,117.266 C322.948,117.266 247.591,197.675 247.591,197.675 C247.591,197.675 261.269,306.993 261.269,306.993 C261.269,306.993 161.469,260.209 161.469,260.209 C161.469,260.209 61.667,306.993 61.667,306.993 C61.667,306.993 75.346,197.675 75.346,197.675 C75.346,197.675 -0.010,117.266 -0.010,117.266 C-0.010,117.266 108.242,96.481 108.242,96.481 C108.242,96.481 161.469,0.007 161.469,0.007", ),    

opts = {
  controlsAboveOverlay: true,
  backgroundColor: 'rgb(255,255,255)',
  clipTo: function (ctx) {
    if (typeof backgroundColor !== 'undefined') {
      ctx.fillStyle = backgroundColor;
      ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 900, 900);
    }
    clipPath.render(ctx);
  }
}
    //obviously this is not going to work
    var reloadShape = JSON.stringify(canvas); 
    canvas.loadFromJSON(reloadShape);
    new fabric.Canvas('imageCanvas', opts);

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should initialize canvas just once in your application, otherwise you will loose content of it.

Later when you choose your clipping path create and assign your clipTo function.
if not needed any other processing you could also do just

```
canvas.clipTo = clipPath._render;
```

without creating the new function.

```
//do this once on your application:
var opts = {
  controlsAboveOverlay: true,
  backgroundColor: 'rgb(255,255,255)',
},
canvas = new fabric.Canvas('imageCanvas', opts);

$('#shape').on('click', function(){

var clipPath = new fabric.Path("M161.469,0.007 C161.469,0.007 214.694,96.481 214.694,96.481 C214.694,96.481 322.948,117.266 322.948,117.266 C322.948,117.266 247.591,197.675 247.591,197.675 C247.591,197.675 261.269,306.993 261.269,306.993 C261.269,306.993 161.469,260.209 161.469,260.209 C161.469,260.209 61.667,306.993 61.667,306.993 C61.667,306.993 75.346,197.675 75.346,197.675 C75.346,197.675 -0.010,117.266 -0.010,117.266 C-0.010,117.266 108.242,96.481 108.242,96.481 C108.242,96.481 161.469,0.007 161.469,0.007", );

  canvas.clipTo = function (ctx) {
    if (typeof backgroundColor !== 'undefined') {
      ctx.fillStyle = backgroundColor;
      ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 900, 900);

    //for clipping _render would be enough.
    // but .render() will allow you to position the path where you want with top and left
    clipPath.render(ctx);
  }
  // display new canvas clipped.
  canvas.renderAll();

});
```

Comment: Thank you @AndreaBogazzi however ctx is coming up as undefined. Any ideas on why?

Comment: it should not. Any chance to put up a fiddle?

Comment: Yes, here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/scottrrr/em1bgcvg/1/ but it states `Cannot read property 'moveTo' of undefined`. Nothing happens after clicking on Apply Shape, but if you click on the canvas area the shape appears (the corner of the star shape, I'm not sure why the alignment would be different than having it hardcoded). Here is the hardcoded version: https://jsfiddle.net/scottrrr/j83zngdh/2/

Comment: the errore comes from you calling canvas.clipTo(); is  not supposed to be called. i update the answer.

Comment: clipTo is coming up as null in the json, I saw that implementation of clipTo serialization was committed in 2013 (https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/commit/2407dbba49bd662ad2dba92bc463dcddb544cf40). So should it be in the json? @AndreaBogazzi